# Telegram bot to wait for user reply

Tags: python, python-2.7, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

The code below is for a **Telegram Bot** which basically takes a person **username** and **password** and verifies it to provide his average expenditures.

The problem as we see is the bot waits for the user to send his username and password for **10 sec** either waste of time (or) not sufficient time was given. How could I program such that the bot waits for user message and then executes the next lines ( wait till the trigger )

```
def highest(intent,chatid,text):
    seq=["What is your Username ?","Password?"]
    send_message(seq[0],chatid)
    time.sleep(6)
    name,chatid = reply_function()
    print name
    send_message(seq[1],chatid)
    time.sleep(6)
    pw,chatid = reply_function()
    print pw
    try:
        flag = obj.validate(name,pw)
        if flag=="Verified":
            for i in obj.avg_transactions():
                send_message(i,chatid)
        else:
            send_message("try again",chatid)
            highest(intent,chatid,text)
     except:
        send_message("try again",chatid)
        highest(intent,chatid,text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [ForceReply](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply) markup with your requests and check replies from user - when reply contains *Username* in `reply_to_message` field of the received [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) then you should send a request for password etc.

---

**Example** (*pseudocode*):

```
// Asking user for username/password
Bot.SendChatAction(update.Message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.Typing);
Bot.SendTextMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "Type your username, please");

// Checking incoming messages for replies
if (update.Message.ReplyToMessage.Text.Contains("your username"))
{
    if (!IsValidUsername(update.Message.ReplyToMessage.Text)) return;
    SaveUsernameToDb(update.Message.Chat.Id, update.Message.ReplyToMessage.Text);
    Bot.SendChatAction(update.Message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.Typing);
    Bot.SendTextMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "Username has been successfully saved!");
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

---

By the way, asking for private data such as username/password in plain-text-chat is quiet unsafe and very bad practice.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the conversation Handler to solve this problem.
All you need to do is to create a function that asks the question, return the state of the the next function and grab the reply from the new function in. Update.message.text